# Array value as condition of if else- JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I've been trying to understand why whenever value of the array I click, it always add the class "foo".

Example: I clicked on London (cities[1], right?) and it added the class foo.

```
var cities = [
document.getElementById('Paris'),
document.getElementById('London'),
document.getElementById('Berlin')
];


for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
  cities[i].onclick = test;

  function test(){
    if(cities[i] === cities[0]) {
      el.classList.add("foo");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `el`?

Comment: the value el is document.getElementById('el');

Comment: As far as I can see it should **never** add the class *foo* instead of **always** since `cities[3] === cities[0]` will never be true. Also you should not be using a function declaration within blocks and be cautious with how function expressions handles closures within loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: my original answer was incorrect, this updated one is right. `addEventListener` returns nothing. Instead, you should use some kind of wrapper to add and remove your listeners, again so that you don't waste resources on listeners that you aren't using:

```
function on (element, eventName, callback) {
    element.addEventListener(eventName, callback);
    return function unregister () {
        element.removeEventListener(callback);
    }
}

function test (event) {
    if (event.currentTarget===cities[0]) {
        event.target.classList.add('foo');
    }
}

var listenerRemovers = cities.map(function (city) {
    return on(city, 'click', test);
});
```

Now you can remove any of these listeners by calling the corresponding function in your `listenerRemovers` array:

```
listenerRemovers.forEach(function (unRegisterFunc) { unRegisterFunc(); });
```

ORIGINAL WRONG ANSWER:

For what it's worth, you're probably better off using `.map` in a case like this, since best practice is to keep a reference to the event listeners so you can cancel them if needed.

```
function test (event) {
    if (event.currentTarget===cities[0]) {
        event.target.classList.add('foo');
    }
}

var listenerHandlers = cities.map(function (city) {
  return city.addEventListener('click', test);
});
```

Comment: Tried that way but then if I add an else if condition, it dont work :(

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are setting the event functions inside a loop.  Each function is using the same value of `i`.

Try to use `this` instead of trying to `cities[i]` inside the function.

```
function test(){
    if(this === cities[0]) {
      el.classList.add("foo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach to achieve this functionality is to use jQuery, here is the idea:

1. In html tags, give those cities a common class, e.g. class="city"
2. $('.city').click(function(){$('.city').addClass('foo')});

jQuery saves you more time and coding efforts.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you are trying to assign a function to a DOM attribute. You are not registering  a listener but modifying the DOM. If you wish to do it this way, you must assign the onclick as `cities[i].onclick = 'test()'`

Also, you should move the function test outside of the for loop to look like the following. The problem is the function test is being declared many times, each with a different 'i' value.

```
for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
  cities[i].onclick = 'test(this)';
}

function test(el){
 if(cities[i] === cities[0]) {
    el.classList.add("foo");
 }
}
```

Comment: You can set the `.onclick` attribute to a function.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick